# Unable to pbcopy at Vim's ED editor

Tags: macos, vim, copy, pwd, pbcopy

I have tried unsuccessfully to copy the pwd to pbcopy as follows

```
pwd | !pbcopy
```

**How can you copy your path in Vim's ED editor** (: -mode)?

Comment: is pbcopy something mac specific?

Comment: If you want to put the pwd into vim :,!pwd will put it into it.

Comment: How about "*p?  the star register is the system clipboard i think

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mykola: to copy the location of my file in vim to clipboard.

Comment: I've edit the answer. I hope I've understood.

Comment: @Mykola: Do you mean to run the two new commands at : in vim? I did it unsuccessfully. I get gett the following error messages: http://dpaste.com/39435/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `:!pwd|pbcopy`?

Use the command

```
cd
```

to the current working directory if needed with the command

```
lcd %:p:h
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The simpler the better :)

Comment: @jmdeldin: What do you mean with the last command? I did not get it to work in Vim.

Comment: It lets you change Vim's current working directory. For example:

    $ cd ~/Documents
    $ vim ../.vimrc

Vim's `cwd == ~/Documents/`, so you could `:lcd %:p:h` so `cwd = ~/`. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of ways

```
in terminal
pwd | !pbcopy
and then in vim
"*p

in vim
:!r pwd
or in insert mode
<C-R>=getcwd()<CR>
or
<C-R>=system('pwd')<CR>
```

Current file location to the clipboard

```
:let @*=expand('%:p:h')
```

Current vim dir to the clipboard

```
:let @*=getcwd()
```

Comment: while you type press Ctrl+r and then type 'getcwd()' and press enter.

Comment: Do you mean to use at Vim : -mode the pwd | !pbcopy? It does not copy the path for me.